# @Async and @Transactional insists in persist already persisted objects JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, asynchronous, transactions

I am doing some persist operations in my @Service class, within a @Async and @Transactional method.

In this method we persists some objects and then we persists new objects related with these already persisted objects inside the same transaction.

JPA throws an exception because he thinks this related objects are not persisted:

```
a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST
```

This is my Service class structure:

```
@Service
public class AsyncOperationsServiceImpl implements AsyncOperationsService {


    @Async
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(CampaignDTO campaignDTO) {
       // saving related objects here throws an exception
    }

}
```

I guess is something related with Transactions and Async methods, because the same code is working when is not Async annotated.

I've also tried using propagation in the Transactional annotation, but is not working.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there are relationship issue with cascade, you need to use `@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` annotation where  declare relation in entity.

Comment: The fact is that If I execute the same code without Async is working Ok, so the cascade should not be necessary... Also, this objects are already persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

This propagation is required in this case, so the transaction is propagated.

```
@Async
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW)
public void save(CampaignDTO campaignDTO) {
   // saving related objects here throws an exception
}
```

No exceptions are thrown in this case, without modifying the cascade types in the entities.